# Can I use save my forms into my local database?

Tags: formio

I'd like to use form.io in order to allow my admin users to create a new forms but I want save all data into my database, not in form.io platform. Is it possible?

I want use form builder but at save time I want save the form structure into my database.

I don't understand if this option is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Step 1: Store your components in your database. If you use the form builder, you can get them by a call to builder.schema.

Step 2: Retrieve your components from your database and render the form.

Step 3: Save the data to your DB.

```
components = {{component string from DB}}

let formio = new Formio.createForm(document.getElementById(element),
    components,
    {
        saveDraft: true,
        readOnly: ((readonly) ? readonly : false)
    }
    ).then(function (form) {

        if (data) {
            var subm = JSON.parse(data)
            form.submission = { data: subm };
        }

        form.on('submit', function (submission) {
            //Submission Code
        });
        form.on('change', function (x) {
            //Change Code
        })
        form.on('error', (errors) => {
            //Error Code
        })
        form.on("render", function () {
            //Any Render Overrides?
        })

}).catch(function (ex) {

});
```

Some of this stuff is well documented. Some - not so much. Lots of trial and error. (Mostly error).

Answer (score 1):

Something similar is what works for me. Note this is for saving the schema for the Form Builder. This schema can be deserialized and used as a source for the Form Renderer

#uglyCodeSry

JavaScript

```
var form;
var formTemplateToSave; // this is the serialized form template to save

window.onload = function() {
var builder = Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, {builder: {}
    }).then((_form) => {
        
        form = _form;
        form.on('change', function(payload) {
            formTemplateToSave = JSON.stringify(form.schema, null, 4);
        });

        formTemplateToSave = JSON.stringify(form.schema, null, 4);
    });
};
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div id='builder'></div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to include the libraries (as well as your usual jquery stuff)

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.form.io/formiojs/formio.full.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdn.form.io/formiojs/formio.full.min.js'></script>
```

You can then save the **formTemplateToSave** variable as the JSON to rehydrate your forms